# Hibernate Validator specification

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

Hibernate Validator spec says that Constraints declared on a superclass getter will be validated along with any constraints defined on an overridden version of the getter according to the Java Language Specification visibility rules. Is there any workaround to deal with constraints defined in Subclass? Assuming that i have class Employee implements interface1 , interface1 extends interface2. We have a field named identifier with size 35 in interface2 and overridden in interface1 with size 75, can we work with the 75 size ??? Thank you,

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to override some fields in your `subclass` ?

Comment: My reason that I want to use the overridden size of the field (field with size 75)

Comment: One way would be to declare the field in an unannotated interface and then extend it in two annotated interfaces: interface35 and interface75